# How can I enable autoscrolling for other applications in Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, mouse, scrolling

Firefox and Chrome have a feature that when you click your middle button and move your mouse up or down from the initial position it will scroll, rather than having to spin the scroll wheel madly.

Is there anything out there that can do this in other / all programs in Ubuntu, such as Libre Writer, Terminal, Gimp, etc...?

Running 13.04 with Logitech M510 mouse.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope**, not unless the application provides explicit support for it.

You may have noticed that autoscroll in Firefox (or Chrome) doesn't work all the time:  if you try to start it over a hyperlink, it middle-clicks the hyperlink, opening it in another tab.  This behavior is application-defined:  obviously it doesn't make much sense to open something in another tab in GIMP!

Likewise, autoscroll is an application-defined behavior.  That's what the scrollbar is there for!